# How do I point two domain names to one server?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, domain-name

I need to point two domain names to one server. It is an Apache Linux server.

I understand that I can create two A records in the DNS pointing to the same IP. But how do I configure the Apache server, mail server, etc.?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your DNS, point both domains to the same IP.

In httpd.conf add a ServerAlias directive for that domain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain1.com
ServerAlias domain2.com
# ...
</VirtualHost>
```

(You may need to look in another file if httpd.conf has any `includes` in it.)

Then restart Apache:

```
service httpd restart
```

For details on configuring Apache name-based hosts look at:
[httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html)